# how to disable / hide only one category cancel request button in wordpresss

Tags: wordpress

If there are 3 categories of product in my pass like mens, womens, and customs then if any person orders something then there is a cancel order button in the mens or womens product order but if he orders a customs product then he has to cancel the order. no button

I have never tried it, but I am expecting that my problem will be solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.